# Java/Android [Direct Print | Photos] Default Color & Orientation global settings not reflecting in print preview

Tags: java, android

Hi currently am working on print plugin application in which i am facing issue in direct print for Default Color & Orientation global settings(option selected from application) not reflecting in print preview.

`​PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder capsBuilder = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(mPrinterId); capsBuilder.setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR | PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCROME, PrintAttributeshdghda.COLOR_MODE_MONOCROME);`

Note:- Every time in case of Photos > Direct Print path, the default color option would show up as "Color" and Orientation as "Landscape"

But its working for PDF document.

[Direct Print | Photos] Default Color & Orientation global settings should reflecting in print preview